# bridge interface causes boot to hang for many minutes

Tags: networking, openvpn, linux-networking, bridge

I have a bridge `br0` which is being used as docker's bridge interface and bridges to our vpn with an ipv6 interface. When I set up this bridge manually, everything works fine and I can connect to the vpn (from my laptop) and ping `bbbb::2000` as well as all the docker containers (e.g. `bbbb::242:ac11:4`) just fine.

Leaving it as a config file, however, causes the boot process to take several minutes with the message `cloud-init-nonet waiting [10|60|120]s for network device` coming up all the time, followed (eventually) by `Waiting up to [60|120] more seconds for network configuration...`. Once it finally boots, the bridge does work but the long restart cycle concerns me.

So my question (amongst other things) is: what is wrong with my configuration file such that boot takes such a long time?

My initial thought was that perhaps having `bridge_ports tap0` in there is causing it to fail to boot until tap0 is up, but removing `bridge_ports` prevents the bridge interface from working at all (and keeps the long boot time) so it must be something else.

#### /etc/network/interfaces.d/br0.cfg

```
# docker bridge network
auto br0
iface br0 inet6 static
   bridge_ports tap0
   bridge_stp off
   up echo 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/multicast_snooping
   post-up ip addr flush tap0
   address bbbb::2000
   netmask 64
```

#### creating the bridge manually

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 tap0
ip addr flush tap0
service docker restart
```